# Restrictions on Generics in java and reflection

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

I was reading this about generics and their restrictions.

> Cannot Create Instances of Type Parameters
>
> You cannot create an instance of a type parameter. For example, the
>   following code causes a compile-time error:
>
> ```
> public static <E> void append(List<E> list) {
>     E elem = new E();  // compile-time error
>     list.add(elem);
> }
> ```
>
> As a workaround, you can create an object of a type parameter through
>   reflection:
>
> ```
> public static <E> void append(List<E> list, Class<E> cls) throws Exception {
>     E elem = cls.newInstance();   // OK
>     list.add(elem);
> }
> ```
>
> You can invoke the append method as follows:
>
> ```
> List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();
> append(ls, String.class);
> ```

I am somewhat confused. I understand why it isn't allowed because that new E() will just turn into new object() because of type erasure, but why doesn't the same thing happen in class.newInstance? I mean it uses the type parameter E, so wouldn't it end up with the same problem? Could someone please explain (I know I have to add the try-catch to get it to compile).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because `cls.newInstance();` is capable of creating `E` instances. It's of type `Class<E>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have noted, the type parameter `E` is just something used by the compiler, it's not instantiated with the generic and cannot be used at run-rime.  The *parameter* `cls`, on the other hand, is a real thing.  It is an object passed in at run-time that has all its type information there to be reflected upon.  The `E` in `cls`'s *type* (recall `Class<E> cls`) *will* be type-erased (after all, `Class` is just another generic) but the *object* `cls` will carry on the information about its type.

Comment: so it will just become Class<Object> cls but since we sent String.class, when you call newInstance() it still returns a new String. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

It will work because the programer calling the method will have to pass a `Class<E>` instance as a parameter (the type of this instance will be checked compile-time before type erasure). This instance will be able at runtime to call the right constructor because it is able to determine its runtime type, which was not possible without an actual instance in the first snippet.